# Do I need to add all the prefixes to a chrome desktop app?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, prefix

I am developing a chrome app and I would lile to know if I only need to add -webkit- prefix or I need to add all the prefixes.

Answer (score 4):

A Chrome app, by definition, runs only in Chrome, which is WebKit-based, and WebKit-only; as such you'd only need the WebKit prefixes, if any.